# Report on opportunities with certain activities?

Tags: soql, query, sosl

How would I create a report that showed all opportunities with at least one activity, whose most recent activity was this month, and contained the word "foo"?

(I'm a total SFDC novice -- if there are downloads or tools required, please mention them!)

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest looking up the Salesforce reporting and analytics workbook. That will give you a good introduction to reporting. If you have trouble please update your question with specific issues instead of something this broad.

Comment: Another resource would be the [Force.com Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) which has a chapter devoted to creating reports. This workbook is the primary resource used to study for the DEV401 Certification Exam.